# Save a JSON document with a list of embedded binary attachments in MarkLogic

Tags: java, marklogic

Given an entity for example:

```
public class Page {
   private String description;
   private List<File> attachments; //is it a File or maybe bytes???
}
```

Is it possible (or even advisable) to save this as a JSON document in MarkLogic with the attachments as embedded documents?

If so:

1. How? Just by using client.newJSONDocumentManager() even if mixed w/ binary data?
2. Will the JSON document's attachments field retain the filename for each File?

Else if not, should I save the page as a JSON document and for each attachment, save as a separate binary document in MarkLogic, but how to relate each other (how can I link them with some sort of foreign key)?

Answer (score 2):

You can organize your data however you choose.  Normally, you would write each binary document/attachment as its own document with its own uri in ML Server.  Generally you would choose the uri for each in your application.  Therefore you could add that list of uris to the parent document.  Something like the following:

```
{ description: "some description",
  attachments: [
     "/my/dir/attachments/attachment_1.bin",
     "/my/dir/attachments/attachment_2.bin",
     "/my/dir/attachments/attachment_3.bin"
  ]
}
```

You can create batches containing both parent documents and binary attachments using DocumentWriteSet.  You could then use JSONDocumentManager.write(documentWriteSet) to send them to the server (see [Writing Multiple Documents](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_54649)).

Comment: Thanks Sam. Did you suggest to do this way, so that when loading the parent document, it would not be forced to load the embedded binary attachments (embedded maybe as some Base64 encoded string)?